# Run docker command with JSch

Tags: java, docker, jsch

I´m using JSch to run a docker command, but it´s not working, and it´s not returning anything.

```
    ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
    channel.setCommand("docker ps -a");
    channel.connect();



 String msg = null;
        while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
```

If I run a bash command as 'pwd' or 'ls -l' works fine.

I can expect that the docker command will work on ChannelExec and not ChannelShell or any other type?

```
session.openChannel("exec")
```

Regards.

Comment: what do you mean by "but it´s not working?"

Comment: It´s not returning any info

Comment: It might be printing something to standard error. You should read that as well.

Comment: And any idea how to do read that standard error?